# Scala Testing with Python unittests

Tags: python, scala, unit-testing

I have a library written in Python complete with unit tests. I'm about to start porting of the functionality to Scala to run on Spark and as part of an Android application. But I'm loath to reproduce the unit tests in scala.

Is there a method for exposing the to-be-written Scala library to external interrogation from Python? I can rewrite the tests to use a command line interface, but I wondered if there were other ways.

I have ruled out Jython because it is not compatible with my existing Python 3 library and unit tests.

Comment: What's the intended audience for your library? If it's not "Scala developers who are also comfortable with Python", you might want to reconsider - given the necessity of unit tests, any new contributor would have to know both languages to help develop your library effectively.

Comment: That is a very good point, the intended audience is simply any Scala developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: Maybe, but don't.

Eventually common sense prevailed. I now aim to either use pyspark or port the unit tests across to Scala along with the rest of the library.

Exposing Scala to Python was achievable by generating Scala code that prints specifically what I wanted. Then from Python calling SBT to compile that code and run it and capture the stdout.
I started mocking the scala version of the same api in Python to create these custom scala scripts and by adding in a compilation step for each query it was getting very slow. As I started considering a command line interface or socket based api for my Mocked Scala classes the reality sunk in.

To answer the actual question of running my existing Python unittests, while I *think* it could still be possible it is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this by using [Py4J](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/) to call your Scala code from Python.  Py4J works in a regular cPython interpreter and [is compatible with Python 3](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/faq.html#can-i-use-py4j-with-python-3).

You will essentially be calling your Scala code from Java, so you'll have to be somewhat aware of how your Scala constructs map onto Java ([here's a decent summary of some of the basic conventions](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/java.html)).  Depending on how your code is written, you might find it easier to implement a Java helper class that exposes a Java-friendly interface to your Scala class / application and call that new Java class from Py4J; this is the approach that we took for PySpark, Spark's Python API ([more details here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/PySpark+Internals)).

Comment: I would advocate trying for using pure pyspark unless you have a good reason to use Scala--adding languages to a project exponentially increases complexity later on.